# Combining Two Images with Matching Features

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-stitching

So basically I am working on trying to combine two images together which overlap each other. I have used the registration estimator app to check and they have matched features. 
My program at the moment picks up the matched features and displays them, with the other image in the background. 
What I want to do is be able to replicate what the registration estimator app does and combine the two images where their features meet.

I have looked at a panorama example but it doesn't seem to work for whatever reason.

```
clear all;
close all;
I1 = rgb2gray(imread('q2.jpg'));
I2 = rgb2gray(imread('q20.jpg'));

points1 = detectSURFFeatures(I1);
points2 = detectSURFFeatures(I2);

[f1, vpts1] = extractFeatures(I1, points1);
[f2, vpts2] = extractFeatures(I2, points2);

indexPairs = matchFeatures(f1, f2) ;
matchedPoints1 = vpts1(indexPairs(:, 1));
matchedPoints2 = vpts2(indexPairs(:, 2));

figure; ax = axes;
showMatchedFeatures(I1,I2,matchedPoints1,matchedPoints2,'Parent',ax);
title(ax, 'Putative point matches');
legend(ax,'Matched points 1','Matched points 2');

% Create new Image ... 
% joinedImg = Combined image where matched points overlap
```

So basically what I need to do is be able to create a new image and imwrite it which is the combined image of the two images. Something like a panorama but not because its just where the points meet and overlap

Comment: The question needs clarifying - what have **you** have tried to do (your code) and where did it fail (what it is doing wrong). An example of something you think is similar doesn't count. Specifically for what you are trying to accomplish, you need to calculate the projection of one image onto the other, then create a larger image that includes both, where in the intersection point you need to decide which image to sample - the first, the second or a function of the two e.g. average.

Comment: I don't know how to that's why, I know I probably have to use imwarp somewhere and resize but no idea how to go about it

Comment: I haven't used Matlab in years, however, image processing is all about maths, you don't really need a library, just think of the two images as plain of points and use linear maths. P.S. Don't forget that pixels consist of RGB subpixels and that lines often end with a padding so that they divide by 4Bytes (or was it 8?). If that still doesn't help you, try reading/watching/attending a course on practical image processing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you chose the wrong example from MATLAB documentation.

You can use [estimateGeometricTransform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimategeometrictransform.html) example.

The following code gives you the transformation `tform`:

```
[tform,inlierPtsDistorted,inlierPtsOriginal] = ...
    estimateGeometricTransform(matchedPtsDistorted,matchedPtsOriginal,...
    'similarity');
```

The warp code is: `Ir = imwarp(distorted,tform,'OutputView',outputView);`

For fusing the images, you can use [imfuse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfuse.html) function.

Following code combines `estimateGeometricTransform` example with `imfuse` example:

```
%https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimategeometrictransform.html
original  = imread('cameraman.tif');
%imshow(original);
%title('Base image');
distorted = imresize(original,0.7); 
distorted = imrotate(distorted,31);
%figure; imshow(distorted);
%title('Transformed image');
ptsOriginal  = detectSURFFeatures(original);
ptsDistorted = detectSURFFeatures(distorted);
[featuresOriginal,validPtsOriginal] = extractFeatures(original,ptsOriginal);
[featuresDistorted,validPtsDistorted] = extractFeatures(distorted,ptsDistorted);
index_pairs = matchFeatures(featuresOriginal,featuresDistorted);
matchedPtsOriginal  = validPtsOriginal(index_pairs(:,1));
matchedPtsDistorted = validPtsDistorted(index_pairs(:,2));
%figure; 
%showMatchedFeatures(original,distorted, matchedPtsOriginal,matchedPtsDistorted);7
%title('Matched SURF points,including outliers');
[tform,inlierPtsDistorted,inlierPtsOriginal] = estimateGeometricTransform(matchedPtsDistorted,matchedPtsOriginal, 'similarity');
%figure; 
%showMatchedFeatures(original,distorted, inlierPtsOriginal,inlierPtsDistorted);
%title('Matched inlier points');
outputView = imref2d(size(original));
Ir = imwarp(distorted,tform,'OutputView',outputView);
%figure; imshow(Ir); 
%title('Recovered image');

%https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfuse.html
C = imfuse(original, Ir, 'falsecolor', 'Scaling', 'joint', 'ColorChannels', [1 2 0]);
figure; imshow(C); 
title('fuse image');

%Write result image to file.
imwrite(C, 'fused.png');
```

It could be helpful if you attach your input images: `'q2.jpg'` and `'q20.jpg'`.